# error creating object using Firebase values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to pull down information from my Firebase database and use it to create an object of type `Order`. The error that I have printed in the catch statement is as follows.

> Error Domain=myProjectName.OrderError Code=0 "(null)"

I am unsure what this means exactly, or how to fix it.
I have defined a custom error type in my Order class, as shown below.

```
enum OrderError: ErrorType
{
    case IllegalOrderNumber
    case InvalidEntry
}
```

The error is generated by the following code snippet.

```
self.ref.child("orders").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let pickupLoc = snapshot.value!["pickupLocation"] as? String
        let dropoffLoc = snapshot.value!["dropoffLocation"] as? String
        let orderNumInt = snapshot.value!["orderNum"] as? Int
        //since the database will return nil if you try and cast a string to an int
        //we get it as an int then cast to string
        let orderNum = String(orderNumInt)

        do
        {
            let myOrder = try Order(PickUpLoc: pickupLoc, DropOffLoc: dropoffLoc, OrderNum: orderNum)!
            self.orders.append(myOrder)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            //should never get here
            print(error)
        }
})
```

I do all of the error checking when the user enters the value into the database, so there should be no reason for there to be an error generated.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and print `error.description`, what it prints?

Comment: it prints as I stated above `Error Domain=myProjectName.OrderError Code=0 "(null)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after combing through my code I noticed two primary possible error sources. Firstly, despite the compiler not complaining, the `do-catch block` was not exhaustive, and therefore an additional `catch` was added to fix this. Secondly, I believe the error was generated by the fact that I declared my `Orders` array as `var orders = [Order()]` as opposed to `var orders = [Order]()`, when I changed this, the program ran smoothly.